# background shell script terminating automatically

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I've created a background shell to watch a folder (with inotifywait) and execute a process (a php script to send information to several other server and update a database, but I don't think that's relevant) when a new file is created in it.

My problem is that after some times the script is actually terminated, and I don't understand why (I redirected the output to a file not to fill up the buffer, even for php execution).

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 server and latest version of php.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#get the script directory
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
script_path=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

for f in `ls "$script_path"/data/`
do
    php myscript.php "$script_path"/data/$f &
done
#watch the directory for file creation
inotifywait -q -m --format %w%f -e create "$script_path"/data/ | while read -r line; do
    php myscript.php "$line" & 
done
```

Comment: most likely due to inotifywait being terminated

Comment: Could you explain how do you run the script. Is it a cron job ? Do you use screen/nohup or other approaches used to run a command even if the session is disconnected or the user logs out ?

Comment: i plan on creating a demon, but for the moment i run it by terminal :
`./myscript.sh &` . I know cron jobs can't run background process (as i already tried that...)

Comment: & don't parse ls. Use glob instead. Unless you are 100% sure that the filenames do not contain any special characters.

Comment: To follow the good advice from @anishsane here, the for loop should be changed like so: `for f in "$SCRIPTPATH"/data/*; do ...; done`

Comment: ...also, ALL expansions need to be quoted. `"$SCRIPT"`, not `$SCRIPT`; `"$LINE"`, not `$LINE`, etc. And the `read` should instead be `read -r`. And the local variables should be lowercase -- all-caps means you can conflict with global or environment variable names.

Comment: Thank you for the advises, concerning the name of my file, they always will be based on the same structure (a timestamp followed by by random alphanumeric charaters) so i'm sure of what is in it. i'll quote all calls to my variables and lower case them, to make sure. come back to you when i made the change and tested.

Comment: same problem, the script is still terminating itself unexpectidly...
i'm going to update myscript in the post to be more accurate...

Comment: after some research, i found that you could use `trap commmand signal` to handle a signal (like sigterm). could i actually relaunch my script using something like that : `trap "myscript.sh &" SIGTERM` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours and hours i finally found a solution, it might (must) be a bit dirty but it works ! As i said in a previous command, i used the trap command, here is my final script :

```
#!/bin/sh

#get the script directory
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
script_path=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

#trap SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM and relaunch the script
trap "pkill -9 inotifywait;($SCRIPT &);exit" 1 2 15

for f in `ls "$script_path"/data/`
do
    php myscript.php "$script_path"/data/$f &
done
#watch the directory for file creation
inotifywait -q -m --format %w%f -e create "$script_path"/data/ | while read -r line; do
    php myscript.php "$line" & 
done
```

hope it will help shell beginner as me :)

Edit : added "pkill -9 inotifywait" to make sure inotify process won't stack up,the parenthesis to make sure the new process is not a child of the current one, and exit to make sure the current process stops running

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `nohup` and `screen` this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: even using nohup, the script still stop working after sometimes, the only way i found to keep it running is re launching it in background.